# How do I get one document from MongoDB with ID from URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm making a basic movie app project, my movie Schema looks like this:

```
const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    genre: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true,
        enum: ['comedy', 'horor', 'romantic', 'action']
    }
});

const Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);
```

I'm trying to get one movie by id but this way it doesn't work

```
async function getMovie(id) {;
    return await Movie
        .find({"_id": {id}})
        .select('name genre')
}


router.get("/:id", async(req, res) => {
    try{
    const movie = await getMovie(req.params.id);
    if (!movie) return res.status(404).send("The genre with the given ID does not exist.");
    console.log(movie);
    res.send(movie);
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log("Error", err)
    }
});
```

I'm getting two errors:

1. Error CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ id:
   '5f74c795cd1c5c22e82c18c6' }" at path "_id" for model "Movie"
2. Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a
   string of 24 hex characters

How should I properly write this code?
Btw using postman for checking requests

Comment: How is the request that you are sending?

Answer (score 0):

I should have used findById method in getMovie() function like this:

```
async function getMovie(id) {;
    return await Movie
        .findById(id)
        .select('name genre')
}


router.get("/:id", async(req, res) => {
    try{
    const movie = await getMovie(req.params.id);
    console.log(movie);
    res.send(movie);
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log("Error", err)
    }
});
```